# Multiply values return in invoked function Power BI

Tags: function, powerbi, powerquery

Is it possible to return for example 2 lists using invoked function? [image]

I cannot find a answer is that even possible.

This is my input table [image]

And for example I want to function return column OrderID and OrderID+1

[image]

Comment: Depends on what you mean exactly. Please edit your question to show your data input (as text which can be copy/pasted into a table) and **also** your desired output (as a screenshot or text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You output shows that what you want for output is not two lists; rather it is a two-column table.

Here is one way to do that:

```
(L as list, A as number) =>

let 
    M = List.Transform(L, each _ + A),
    T = Table.FromColumns({L,M},{"OrderID","OrderID2"})
in 
    T
```

Here is the code from the invoked function:

```
let
    Source = fnAdd(Table[OrderID], 1)
in
    Source
```

where `Table[OrderID]` is the `OrderID` column of your input table

**first two columns of data input table**
[image]

**output from invoked function**
[image]